# Accidentally made a folder called '.. and now windows says it can't find it to delete it

Tags: windows, windows-10

I accidentally changed a folder name to be `'..`, and now whenever I try to delete it, windows is saying it can't find the file or folder specified.  I need to delete it though because it's messing up the git repo

Comment: Does the folder show up in the Open dialog in Notepad?  Can you right click and delete it from there?

Comment: You should be able to delete it from the command prompt

Comment: Robocopy might be able to remove it. But be careful, it's dangerous, sometimes.

Comment: @B540Glenn it does show, but I can't delete it from there.  Same error

Comment: @LPChip I tried that and it still told me it couldn't find it

Comment: @Herb how does that work?  I've never used robocopy before

Comment: @herb I tried `robocopy '.. asdf` and it gave me the same error about not being able to find it

Comment: In `cmd`, if you type `dir /x` in the parent directory, you will see its 8.3 name, and you can use this in the `rmdir` command.

Comment: Since David Postill marked the duplicate, I now see it is one of the answers in his link.